# Regular Expression (Regex) to allow numbers 0.1 to 100.0

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, validation

I'm continuing to cleanup a mess of a site at my workplace and am almost done adding validation, I have this one issue remaining.

I have a number that is set by default to 100.0. I need to allow input from 0.1 to 100.0. I currently have an expression that works but allows 0 and 0.0 and 00.0, and these values crash my program.
Here is my current expression:

```
^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1})?|100(\.0?)?)$
```

The current expression allows numbers such as 0.2 .2 and 00.2, that is fine, I just can't have it accept 00.0, 0.0 and 0.

Again, this is numbers only, one or no decimals, and 0.1 to 100.0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're open to other methods, I would consider using a range validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^(0\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{,2}\.[0-9])$
```

This will match either a `0.`, followed by a digit from `1` to `9`, or a digit from `1` to `9` followed by zero, one or two digits from `0` to `9`, a `.` and another digit from `0` to `9`.

An alternative solution would be using a lookahead:

```
^(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,3}\.\d$
```

This will match one to three digits, followed by a `.`, and another digit, but only if that sequence contains a digit from `1` to `9`.

However, I'd recommend just parsing the number as a decimal and checking it's range directly.